# Where to initialize an instance of a class in a multiple file python code?

Tags: python, oop

I working on a project that is broken into multiple files, and while I know my issue is that I'm not initializing an instance of the class I'm trying to use, I can't figure out where to do so. The two files are below - the DataLayer and the main file. The issue in question is under the first button - I'm passing data entered by the user to the DataLayer and attempting to use a method (d_read_from_pandas_all) in that class. The method's only parameter is "self." What am I missing here?

```
from DataLayer import *
from ViewLayer import *
class NotebookDemo(Frame):

    def __init__(self, isapp=True, name='notebookdemo'):
        Frame.__init__(self, name=name)
        self.pack(expand=Y, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title('Inventory Data Cleaner')
        self.isapp = isapp
        self._create_widgets()

    def _create_widgets(self):
        self._create_demo_panel()

    def _create_demo_panel(self):
        demoPanel = Frame(self, name='demo')
        demoPanel.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=Y)

        # create the notebook
        nb = Notebook(demoPanel, name='notebook')
        nb.enable_traversal()

        nb.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=Y, padx=2, pady=3)
        self._create_descrip_tab(nb)
        self._create_view_tab(nb)
        self._create_text_tab(nb)



    def _create_descrip_tab(self, nb):
        # frame to hold contentx
        frame = Frame(nb, name='descrip')

        # widgets to be displayed on 'Description' tab

        docName = tk.StringVar()
        docLabel = tk.Label(frame, text = 'enter cruise document name')
        docEntry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable = docName)

        btn = Button(frame, text='Load', underline=0,
           command=lambda: [DataLayer(str(docName)), DataLayer.d_read_from_pandas_all()])
        #

        # position and set resize behaviour
        btn.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(2, 4))
        docLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = (2,4))
        docEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = (2,4))

        frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        frame.columnconfigure((0, 1), weight=1, uniform=1)

        # add to notebook (underline = index for short-cut character)
        nb.add(frame, text='View Data', underline=0, padding=0)


    # =============================================================================
    def _create_view_tab(self, nb):
        # Populate the second pane. Note that the content doesn't really matter
        frame = Frame(nb, name="view")
        btn1 = Button(frame, text='Click here to view data', underline=0,
                      command=lambda:[DataLayer.d_read_from_pandas_all(self, docName), ViewLayer.create_display_table(self,frame), ViewLayer.viewTable(self)])

        btn1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(2, 4))

        nb.add(frame, text='Check Data', underline=0, padding=2)

    # =============================================================================
    def _create_text_tab(self, nb):
        # populate the third frame with a text widget
        frame = Frame(nb)

        txt = Text(frame, wrap=WORD, width=40, height=10)
        vscroll = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=txt.yview)
        txt['yscroll'] = vscroll.set
        vscroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        txt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=Y)

        # add to notebook (underline = index for short-cut character)
        nb.add(frame, text='Text Editor', underline=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    NotebookDemo().mainloop()
```

```
import pandas as pd


class DataLayer:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename




    def d_read_from_pandas_all(self):
        global df
        df = pd.read_csv(self.filename, index_col=0)
        print(df.head(10))

        return df
```

Answer (score 0):

To import a Class from anothor file you need to import it like:

```
from file import class
```

this also works if you have structured your files in folders:

```
from folder.file import class
```

assuming your `DataLayer` class is saved in `datalayer.py` within the same directory you would need to import:

```
from datalayer import DataLayer
```

if you would save you seperate classes in a folder called `classes`that is in the same directory like your main file, you would import:

```
from classes.datalayer import DataLayer
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that's what I'm doing with "from DataLayer import *" The error I'm getting is                               
    command=lambda: [DataLayer(str(docName)), DataLayer.d_read_from_pandas_all()])
TypeError: d_read_from_pandas_all() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'